# redirect reverse in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm working on Django 1.11

I want to redirect user from view.

contents of `myapp/accounts/urls.py`

```
app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    url(r'^profile/', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile')
]
```

and in `myapp/accounts/views.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, UpdateView

class ProfileView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/profile.html'

class UpdateProfile(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    template_name = 'accounts/update.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, 'Profile Updated Successfully')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
```

This is giving error on redirect.

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/update/

Reverse for 'profile' not found. 'profile' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

**How to redirect user to `profile` page after updating profile details?**

**How to redirect user to other app's view?**

Comment: Name of `url` should be unique, you are using `name='profile'` for 2 urls

Comment: I'm using name for both because I want to redirect `www.example.com/accounts` and `www.example.com/accounts/profile` to the same view.

Comment: removed line `url(r'^$', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),`, still same error

Comment: Are you using namespace in the project url file? Then you may need to specify the app name along with the view name like this : 'accounts:profile'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you need to give `unique names`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    url(r'^profile/', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='detailprofile')
]
```

**Now**

```
def get_success_url(self):
    messages.success(self.request, 'Profile Updated Successfully')
    return reverse('accounts:profile')
```